# Is there a way of getting the executable file's name in C without using argv[0]

Tags: c, cross-platform, command-line-arguments, compile-time-constant

This question is just out of curiosity. I thought there might be a predefined macro or something but couldn't find anything. If impossible, is it appropriate to use a constant global variable initiated with argv?

I really don't know why the question was closed. The stated justification is that an answer already exists here:[Finding current executable's path without /proc/self/exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023306/finding-current-executables-path-without-proc-self-exe)

The referred question has platform-specific answers and is also tagged with C++, which is a whole different story on the topic with boost. I just tagged C and compiler-constants just in case there is a method I didn't know about to accomplish the task of keeping track of the executable file identifier.

Comment: No.  argv is a runtime value.  there may be other ways that are platform-dependent.

Comment: There is no way this can be known in compile time. You can rename the executable after it was compiled.

Comment: It would be system dependent. For example, on most Unixes you could look up the process ID in [/proc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/proc.html) and get the executable name.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I thought about that too but wouldn't it be okay to assign argv[0] to whatever runtime constant you want. Since no one wants to work with global vars, I think that would be a good idea.

Comment: @Schwern frankly speaking, if you're not coding cross-platform and dealing with platform-specific libraries, system calls, etc., just use bash. GNU core utils just work fine.

Comment: @OmerErbilgin "runtime constant" seems like an oxymoron, what do you mean by that? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Schwern for example if the gcc compiler pointed argv[0] to a char *, wouldn't that be a runtime constant?

Comment: @OmerErbilgin You can do `const char *exename; int main(int argv, char **argv) { exename = argv[0]; ... }`, but now you've got a global variable.

Comment: @Schwern Exactly, but would you consider this good practice?  I would consider appropriate argument parsing using a separate file/function without passing argv or using an extend (using getopt maybe).

Comment: @OmerErbilgin Depends why you need it. If it's just for argument parsing, probably not. If you need the executable name globally for some reason, maybe.