# How to bundle OpenSSL v3 binaries with application on Windows?

Tags: windows, openssl, binaries

How to bundle OpenSSL v3 binaries with application on Windows?

Withing executable I have `libcrypto-3-x64.dll` and `libssl-3-x64.dll`.

In `./lib` directory I have `DLLs` in `engines-3` and `ossl-modules`.

Good, but to start application I forced to use `*.bat` file with something like:

```
set OPENSSL_MODULES=./lib/ossl-modules
set OPENSSL_ENGINES=./lib/engines-3
start "" my_app.exe %
```

How to avoid using of this `*.bat` file, and have only `my_app.exe` that won't produce Windows error message?

Want to add that:

```cpp
int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    qputenv( "OPENSSL_MODULES", "./lib/ossl-modules" );
    qputenv( "OPENSSL_ENGINES", "./lib/engines-3" );
```

doesn't solve the problem.

And a following `*.manifest`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"></requestedExecutionLevel>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
      <environment name="OPENSSL_MODULES" value="./lib/ossl-modules" />
      <environment name="OPENSSL_ENGINES" value="./lib/engines-3" />
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>
</assembly>
```

doesn't solve the problem too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `bat` file works but this code does not:

```
int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    qputenv( "OPENSSL_MODULES", "./lib/ossl-modules" );
    qputenv( "OPENSSL_ENGINES", "./lib/engines-3" );
```

that means you have to set the environment variables before the OS loads the process.

So do just that.  **Re**-load the process after you set the envvals:

```
int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    QByteArray envval = qgetenv( "OPENSSL_MODULES" );

    // assumes a "default constructed" QByteArray will
    // return true here - not tested
    if ( ennval.isEmpty() )
    {
        qputenv( "OPENSSL_MODULES", "./lib/ossl-modules" );
        qputenv( "OPENSSL_ENGINES", "./lib/engines-3" );

        execv( argv[ 0 ], argv );
        perror( "execv" );
        exit( 1 );
    }
    .
    .
    .
```

Headers and error checking have been omitted to keep the code example short enough so it doesn't have a vertical scroll bar.

And [turn off Microsoft's risible, "We've deprecated every portable non-Microsoft thing we can get away with" "warning"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-3-c4996?view=msvc-170#turn-off-the-warning)

Note that those envvals assume the current working directory is the parent of that particular `lib` directory.  You can add quite a bit of robustness and remove the requirement by [finding the absolute path of the application binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023306/finding-current-executables-path-without-proc-self-exe) first and then use that to determine the absolute path to the `lib` directory.