# Get real path of application from pid?

Tags: macos, process, macos-carbon, bsd

How can I get the process details like name of application & real path of application from process id?

I am using Mac OS X.

Comment: I did not understand your comment. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Could be a duplicate of [Finding current executable's path without /proc/self/exe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023306/finding-current-executables-path-without-proc-self-exe)?

Comment: I dont think its duplicate. Here different application is asking for path based on pid.

Comment: Not a duplicate, because OS X doesn't have /proc, only Linux does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically retrieving the absolute path of an OS X command-line app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/799679/608639). It includes fetching the process pid and then calling `proc_pidpath`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It's quite easy to get the process name / location if you know the PID, just use proc_name or proc_pidpath. Have a look at the following example, which provides the process path:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <libproc.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    pid_t pid; int ret;
    char pathbuf[PROC_PIDPATHINFO_MAXSIZE];

    if ( argc > 1 ) {
        pid = (pid_t) atoi(argv[1]);
        ret = proc_pidpath (pid, pathbuf, sizeof(pathbuf));
        if ( ret <= 0 ) {
            fprintf(stderr, "PID %d: proc_pidpath ();\n", pid);
            fprintf(stderr, "    %s\n", strerror(errno));
        } else {
            printf("proc %d: %s\n", pid, pathbuf);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: URL to Alen's blog entry on this: http://astojanov.wordpress.com/2011/11/16/mac-os-x-resolve-absolute-path-using-process-pid/

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, thanks Alen! Surprising how hard it is to find this information online --- all the Linux heads insist that /proc should work. :-)

Comment: A note about the proc_pidpath function: the buffer size MUST be PROC_PIDPATHINFO_MAXSIZE. If you specify a smaller size, the call fail, even though the dimension would be enough to fit the complete path.

Comment: this works as expected, can someone help on how we can find the "version" of a running process (or say application)

Comment: I get segmentation fault when I call `proc_pidpath`. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I wonder how this proc_path low-level buffer handles paths that are employing strange Unicode names in the directories and binary file-names and how one can interpret this buffer on MacOS. After all you can build a program whose (executable) name contains diacrticals, Chinese, Arabic, Hebrew, Emojis or a combination of the all of them. It is pretty strange that no high-level (Cocoa/Foundation) level API exists for doing this outside of the Bundle and NSRunningApplication API's

Answer (score 32):

You can use the Activity Monitor - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_Monitor

Or in the Terminal App you can use:

```
ps xuwww -p PID
```

`PID`is the process id you are looking for
More help on 'ps`command you can find with

```
man ps
```

Comment: Is this downvoted because the app name is not returned? `ps [PID]` worked for me when I needed it just now - I did have to infer the name of the application from the path, admittedly.

Comment: @Qix it can be by using `Process` (AKA `NSTask`), setting its launch path to `/bin/bash`, its arguments to `["-c", "ps xuwww -p \(pid)"]`, and its `standardOutput` to a `Pipe` you control

Comment: @BenLeggiero That is terrible software engineering practice and should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: @Qix I agree! That's why I didn't offer it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 11):

Try use lsof

example:

`lsof -p 1066 -Fn | awk 'NR==2{print}' | sed "s/n\//\//"`

output:
`/Users/user/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages`

Comment: not working on Mac OS 10.12.1. It was `lsof -p 22558 -Fn | awk 'NR==5{print}' | sed "s/n\//\//"`

Answer (score 5):

If the PID is the PID of a "user application", then you can get the `NSRunningApplication` of the app like that:

```
NSRunningApplication * app = [NSRunningApplication  
    runningApplicationWithProcessIdentifier:pid
];
```

And to print the path of the executable:

```
NSLog(@"Executable of app: %@", app.executableURL.path);
```

the app bundle itself is here

```
NSLog(@"Executable of app: %@", app.bundleURL.path);
```

However this won't work with system or background processes, it's limited to user apps (those typically visible in the dock after launch). The `NSRunningApplication` object allows to to check if the app is ative, to hide/unhide it and do all other kind of neat stuff.

Just thought I mention it here for completeness. If you want to work with arbitrary processes, then the accepted answer is of course better.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to make a better ssh-copy-id in bash only!!
For that, i have to know where is sshd to ask him his actual config. 
On some system i have multiple sshd and which is not my friend. 
Also on some macOS the ps command didn't show the full path for sshd.

```
lsof -p $PPID | grep /sshd | awk '{print $9}'
```

this return

```
/usr/sbin/sshd
```

after i could ask for

```
sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -T | grep authorizedkeysfile
```

this return, on some system

```
authorizedkeysfile .ssh/authorized_keys
```

so i have to put in .ssh/authorized_keys