# fopen not defaulting to current directory

Tags: c, gcc, fopen, apple-m1

I'm using a new mac with macOS Monterey and the M1 Max chip. I'd like `fopen` to default to the current directory when no path is given (this is what I'm used to and I think is the norm), but it's defaulting to my user folder. So, for example, when I compile the below code, the resultant app, regardless of where it is, will only open file.txt if that file is in my user folder (I get a segmentation fault if it's anywhere else). Similarly, if I have the code make a new file with `FILE* fp = fopen("new file.txt", "w");`, the new file will appear in my user folder.
I'm compiling with gcc (that I had downloaded via downloading the newest version of Eclipse) from Terminal with the command:

> `gcc -std=c99 main.c -o yo`

When I build using Eclipse or leave out `-std=c99` I have the same issue.

Also, for gcc --version I get:

> InstalledDir:
> nathanschmidt@nathans-MacBook-Pro ~ % gcc --version Configured with:
> --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
> Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.27.3) Target:
> arm64-apple-darwin21.3.0 Thread model: posix InstalledDir:
> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE* fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    printf("%d\n", fp);
    int x;
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &x);
    fclose(fp);
    printf("%d\n", x);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: From where are you running the executable?

Comment: Why are you using `%d`  to write addresses?

Comment: "I'd like fopen to default to the current directory when no path is given (this is what I'm used to and I think is the norm), but it's defaulting to my user folder". `fopen` has no idea what your user folder is, or what a folder is for that matter. It gets a file path and passes it to the OS. The OS knows that all relative paths go to the current directory. If they go to your user folder, then that's what your current directory is.

Comment: Can I have my current directory be wherever the executable is being run from? That's how it works when I compile the code in Windows.

Comment: @Fra93: Wherever the executable is being run from, it will treat my user folder as the current directory. I used `%d` to print the address to see if it was 0.

Comment: Where you executable is has nothing to do with your current directory. Unix is not Windows.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. : Ok, I'm new to Unix coming from Windows. Can I have the executable open files from the same folder it's in and have that folder's location be variable?

Comment: There is no standard way for an executable to determine in which directory it resides. There may be some Apple-specific non-portable way but I am not aware of it.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511864/get-real-path-of-application-from-pid) is one such method. An executable can determine its own PID with `getpid()`.

Comment: You did not yet answer where and how you start your program. Do you call it from the command line? Do you double-click some link? -- The correct way to print pointers is by `printf("%p\n", (void*)fp);`. And you should guard the following code by a conditional to avoid the segmentation fault.

Comment: Windows executables work the same way.