# Know which Mac process is loading my library framework

Tags: c++, macos, frameworks

I created a C++ library that I compile as a .framework so other apps can call into it. I'd like to get the path of the calling .app file from within the library. How can I do this?

In Windows, I simply call GetModuleFileName with the processID as NULL and it returns the parent process. I want to do the equivalent on Mac.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sysctl(CTL_KERN, KERN_PROC ...)` as documented on this [MacOSX Guru](http://www.macosxguru.net/article.php?story=20060629075017862) page.

```
int getprocessname( pid_t inPID, char *outName, size_t inMaxLen)
{
struct kinfo_proc info;
size_t length = sizeof(struct kinfo_proc);
int mib[4] = { CTL_KERN, KERN_PROC, KERN_PROC_PID, inPID };

if (sysctl(mib, 4, &info, &length, NULL, 0) < 0)
    return -1 ;
else
    strncpy(outName, info.kp_proc.p_comm, inMaxLen) ;

return 0    ;
}
```

See also [this code](http://www.nightproductions.net/dsprocessesinfo_m.html) which retrieves all the structures you need.

Comment: This is good but I'm only getting the process name. How can I get the process's full path? The reason I ask is because I want to calculate a checksum on it.

Comment: Got my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799679/programatically-retrieving-the-absolute-path-of-an-os-x-command-line-app