# Tmux: How do I find out the currently running version of tmux?

Tags: tmux

I know that I can run `tmux -V` to find the version of `tmux` that is in my `PATH`, but how can I get the version of `tmux` that is *currently running*?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Most obvious, but not 100% correct way is to execute this command in console

```
$ tmux -V
```

and receive output like this `tmux 2.9a` with version of tmux  INSTALLED, not currently running.
In 99% cases it is enough, but there can be subtle nuances.

Command `tmux -V`  will return version of tmux installed at /usr/bin/tmux or any other directory inside your PATH variable. If you have tmux already running, it is possible that tmux can be started from binary of other version and from different place (for example, tmux can be started from `/home/user/bin/tmux`).
In this case, you have to call

```
$ ps  -e | grep tmux
```

to see PID of all tmux processes currently running. It will output something like this

```
[vodolaz095@ivory ~]$ ps -e | grep tmux
19699 pts/0    00:00:00 tmux: client
19701 ?        00:00:00 tmux: server
```

Here, number 19701 depicts process id (PID) of currently running tmux server.

After getting PID of tmux server, you can ran command

```
$ lsof -p 19701
```

to get information about CURRENTLY RUNNING tmux server process (in my case its 19701) that will output something like this (Figure 1)

```
COMMAND     PID       USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE  SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
tmux:\x20 19701 vodolaz095  cwd    DIR               8,33      4096 22544385 /home/vodolaz095
tmux:\x20 19701 vodolaz095  rtd    DIR                8,1      4096        2 /
tmux:\x20 19701 vodolaz095  txt    REG                8,1    677760  3675332 /usr/bin/tmux
tmux:\x20 19701 vodolaz095  mem    REG                8,1   6406312   131327 /var/lib/sss/mc/group
```

as you can see, tmux currently running was executed from binary placed in /usr/bin/tmux.

Or, you can call one liner

```sh
    lsof -p `pgrep 'tmux: server'`
```

to achieve the same output as Figure 1

After you get path to tmux binary CURRENTLY RUNNING, (in my case, it was `/usr/bin/tmux`), you can execute this binary with flag -V to get its version

```sh
/usr/bin/tmux -V
```

or, if tmux was installed by limited user into `/home/user/bin/tmux`,

```sh
/home/user/bin/tmux -V
```

And, as result, you'll get version of tmux currently running, not the one, that  was installed.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this won't work if `tmux` has been upgraded since the given process was started.

Comment: In MacOsX I have an error
`ps: option requires an argument -- u`

Comment: just run `tmux -V`, tested on Ubuntu and OSX

Comment: this method will require you to execute tmux first; instead you could use `which tmux` to find out the path

Comment: @Shiva - question author said "version of tmux that is currently running?" - so tmux is running already

Comment: what if we have multiple server versions?

Comment: `ps -u` does not list all a user's processes.  It lists a user friendly output.  For example:
```bash
ps -u $(whoami) | grep tmux
 3089 ?        00:03:36 tmux: server
 5922 pts/3    00:00:00 tmux: client
ps -u | grep tmux
user    5922  0.0  0.0  19336  2752 pts/3    S+   12:24   0:00 tmux attach -d
```

ps -u totally misses the tmux server, pid=3089.

It also doesn't work on BSD, so no macOS.  It also doesn't give the full path to tmux, so you don't know which tmux started the process.  Even so, if that path is now a different executable, it wouldn't even help you then.

Comment: THIS IS WRONG!   THE CORRECT ANSWER IS FROM USER whatintheworld

Answer (score 215):

As pointed out in a comment, `tmux -V` returns the version:

```
$ tmux -V
tmux 3.0a
```

Tested on Centos 7 and OSX 12.5.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. I'm not sure why it's rated so highly. That command just returns the version of whatever tmux is in my path.

Comment: It's because this shows up as the first result of *How to get tmux version*.

Comment: THIS IS WRONG! THE CORRECT ANSWER IS FROM USER whatintheworld

Comment: @iconoclast for me, this and the other answer you mentioned, both of them worked.

Comment: @ssi-anik:  It appeared to work.  That switch was added at a certain point, so it began to work to show you the _first installed version found in your PATH,_ which is not necessarily the same as _the version you're running._  As time goes by you're less and less likely to run into versions of `tmux` not supporting `-V`, and most of the time you aren't likely to be running one version and having another that appears first in your PATH.  But if you really specifically want to know the _**currently running**_ version, then this is not reliable for 2 reasons.

Comment: Since the question itself mentioned `-V` as not acceptable, why would you think this answers the question???  It specifically excluded this as an answer!

Comment: It was edited to exclude this answer after-the-fact.

Comment: As far as I see the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26705755/revisions), `tmux -V` was explicitly excluded from the beginning when the question was asked on Nov 11, 2014. You answered the question on Jun 11, 2016.

Answer (score 30):

To get the version of the tmux **server** you can use `display-message`:

```
./tmux2.3 display-message -p "#{version}"
```

Will show the version of the server (2.7 in my case)

`-p` will direct the output of stdout so you can script with it and `{version}` can be anything from the FORMATS section in the man page.

The following will give you the executable of your tmux server, on Linux:

```
realpath /proc/$(tmux display-message -p "#{pid}")/exe
```

And on macos, `proc_pidpath` can be used, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8149380

Comment: The `/proc` hack is Linux only (and possibly Solaris etc; but not generally portable)

Comment: display-message is the perfect solution for getting the server version!

Comment: In a running tmux client, you can do `:display-message -p "#{version}"`

Comment: @quant This should be the selected answer since the display-message approach actually returns the actively running tmux version and as pointed out that could differ from the currently installed one if there was an update after starting the instance. Alltough I simply run "display-message -p "#{version}" in tmux itself using <prefix>: as oposed to calling the binary.

Comment: On macos, `/proc/` won't work but this does: `proc_pidpath` (which can be wrapped into an executable to be called from bash if needed), see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8149380

Comment: BEWARE depending on the version mismatch between tmux client & server`tmux display-message -p "#{pid}"` works immediately, but trying to capture `$()` or pipe `|` that command into into another command can output the correct answer **then hang forever**!!   

For me (centos 4.1 uptime 400+ days), `ls -l /proc/13802/exe` --> `/usr/bin/tmux;60a77fb0 (deleted)`.
OLD:  `/proc/13802/exe -V  ## 3.1b`.
NEW:  `/usr/bin/tmux -V  ## 3.2a`.  

`tmux display-message -p "#{pid}" | cat` <-- hangs until ^C.
`echo $(tmux display-message -p "#{pid}")/exe`  <-- ^C has no effect

Comment: This solution still seems to fail when there are multiple sessions whose server versions are different.

Answer (score 16):

To find the actual version of the tmux that is running, you have to find the PID of the tmux:

```
pgrep tmux
```

With this info, you can check the version by running:

```
lsof -p $tmuxPID | grep REG | grep -i -e deleted -e "tmux$"
```

If there is not a (deleted) next to the tmux file listed, you can just run that file with a `-V`.

If it results in files that are "(deleted)", you are running an old, uninstalled version.  If you are on linux, you can figure out what it is by running:

```
/proc/$tmuxPID/exe -V`
```

If you are on OS X, you are stuck with whatever information is in the path to the filename, possibly something like `Cellar/tmux/<version number>/bin/tmux`.

You can combine many of these steps into the following one-liner:

```
for tmuxPID in $(pgrep tmux); do lsof -p $tmuxPID | grep REG | grep -i -e deleted -e "tmux$"; done
```

Or if you are on Linux, this always works:

```
for tmuxPID in $(pgrep tmux); do /proc/$tmuxPID/exe -V; done
```

Answer (score 8):

Send prefix (default: ctrl-B) and then type:

```
:display-message "#{version}"
```

this will display version in the status bar