# How to get command line of running program on Mac OS X?

Tags: c++, c, macos, command-line

I want a utility function that returns the full command line of the program from which it is called. In other words,

```
std::string cmd_line();

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
   std::cout << "the current program command line is \""
             << cmd_line() << "\"\n";
}
```

(or the equivalent C program) compiled with `c++ -o my_program test.cc` should produce upon running with `my_program x=7`

```
the current program command line is "my_program x=7"
```

Now, under linux, I manage to simply read this off `/proc/pid/cmdline` where the `pid` is obtained by `getpid()` (from `unistd.h`). What can I do under Mac OS? Is there a more portable way?

---

***Note 1 added in Edit*** In the above example, one could of course simply use `argv[]`. But I want `cmd_line()` to be useable from third party library function w/o knowledge of `argv[]`. So, one would need to provide the `argv[]` information to the library providing `cmd_line()` at initialisation. Can be done, but is somewhat cumbersome. I'm looking for a way to exploit the program initialisation of the run-time system itself.

***Note 2 added in Edit*** The related problem of obtaining the (absolute or relative) path of the running executable is subject of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799679/programatically-retrieving-the-absolute-path-of-an-os-x-command-line-app/1024933#1024933).

Comment: Isn't there a `/proc/pid/cmdline` in Mac OS X?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf not on my macbook. But perhaps it's not at `/`?

Comment: @LPs An implementation in C or C++ would be acceptable

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1024933/2836621

Comment: My first attempt to find the answer would be to look up how it works on FreeBsd - as that is basically the closest relative to OS X...

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't just use the contents of `argv[]` ?

Comment: @PaulR Well, for my simple example above this could be done. But I want `cmd_line()` to be callable form other library functions which know nothing about `argv[]`. So, for this solution one would need to pass `argv[]` (at program initialisation) to the library providing the function `cmd_line()`. Can be done, but is cumbersome and requires a re-write of the initialisation process(es).

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/sysctl.3.html

Comment: @MarkSetchell That question is concerned about the (absolute) path of the running executable. This is a related problem, but AFAICS, it does not prove the command line arguments.

Comment: @RichardHodges That seems relevant, but is rather opaque. Do you have a solution based on `sysctl()`?

Comment: @Walter i'm afraid i don't. I found this by googling "/proc equivalent on OSX". You will find all Apple documentation opaque and cryptic I'm afraid. They seem to hate their developer community :)

Comment: @PaulR FYI some relevant code link in the answer to the post you pointed at as original seems dead.

Comment: @user3078414: yes, that's the trouble with link-based answers - the links tend to go stale after a while. The accepted answer looks good though.